# Is my integration correct or wrong?

Tags: probability-theory

Is my integration correct or wrong?
I have doubts with these:

$$ P(x+y<1/2)=\int_{0}^{1/2} \! \int_{0}^{1/2-y} \! f(x,y) \, dx dy $$

$$ P(x+y>1/2)=\int_{0}^{1} \! \int_{1/2-y}^{1} \! f(x,y) \, dx dy $$

To conclude how can I make sure if my integration is correct? Are there any indicators? Please, help me how can I defend it.

Thank you.

Comment: Sum of those two must be one.

Comment: And this assumes that $f=0$ outside of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: What two? Can you please elaborate? Please.

Comment: Is it correct? Both of them?

Comment: No, the second one is wrong.

Comment: The probability of something occurring is equal to one. Hence the probability of those two must be one (under suitable condition). No one can determine you are correct or not unless you specify what $f$ and $P$ are.

Comment: How should it be? How can I defend it? I want my professor to check her teaching us the wrong way. The first one is my revision of her example, cause it doesn't answer correctly. The second one, I don't know how to revise it. Please help. I attend her class daily but I always sensed something is missing.

Comment: Taro, That's right. I assumed that the density f(x,y) is different from 0 only in the unit square.

Comment: f (x,y) { 24xy, 0<x<1, 0<y<1 and x+y<1 and 0,elsewhere

Comment: With the P(x+y<1/2) using my revise integration I got 1/16 which is correct and if I use our professor's integration the answer is wrong. So I am also doubtful of what is the correct P(x+y>2) would be.

Comment: Suggestion: re-edit so that your question completes. (It is hard to see what your $f$ and $P$ are.)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of a pair $(X,Y)$ that take values in $\left[0,1\right]^2$.
If so then you could write:

$$P\left[X+Y<\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left[x+y<\frac{1}{2}\right]f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$$
$$P\left[X+Y>\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left[x+y>\frac{1}{2}\right]f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$$
where $$\left[x+y<\frac{1}{2}\right]:\left[0,1\right]^{2}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $$
$$\left[x+y>\frac{1}{2}\right]:\left[0,1\right]^{2}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $$
denote the characteristic function of the sets: $$\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]^{2}\mid x+y<\frac{1}{2}\right\} $$
$$\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]^{2}\mid x+y>\frac{1}{2}\right\} $$
respectively.

If you are using a density $f:\left[0,1\right]^{2}\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right)$
then that results in $$P\left[X+Y<\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-y}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$$
$$P\left[X+Y>\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\left\{ 0,\frac{1}{2}-y\right\} }^{1}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$$

Note that we have $\max\left\{ 0,\frac{1}{2}-y\right\} $ instead of $\frac{1}{2}-y$
because $f\left(x,y\right)$ is not defined for a negative $x$.

To avoid this you could use a density on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that coincides with
the original on $\left[0,1\right]^{2}$ and is $0$ elsewhere.

**Example**

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right)$ by $f\left(x,y\right)=1$
if $\left(x,y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]^{2}$ and $f\left(x,y\right)=0$
otherwise. Then

$\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}1dxdy=1$
showing that $f$ is a density. Here:

$P\left[X+Y>\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{1}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$.

If $y\leq\frac{1}{2}$ then $\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{1}f\left(x,y\right)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{1}dx=y+\frac{1}{2}$

If $y>\frac{1}{2}$ then $\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{1}f\left(x,y\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x,y\right)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{0}f\left(x,y\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}-y}^{0}0dx=1$

This leads to $P\left[X+Y>\frac{1}{2}\right]=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)dy+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}1dy=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{8}$.

Comment: So If I am using a density function I will use the second one? So, when will I use the first one?

Comment: In *both* cases you use a density function. In the first a density that is defined on $[0,1]^2$ in the second a density that is defined on  $\mathbb R^2$. They will give the same result.

Comment: So you mean they get the same answer. I am comfortable with the sec ond one but to be honest I don't feel connected by the first one. Can you please elaborate the first one, an example on how to solve it so I will have far knowledge with it. Our prob professor is always lacking. She will just give exams like level 5 but she teaches us like level 1. Feel bad about it. I like the professor before her, she is a replacement. The guy professor is more understandable.

Comment: An example is added.